# How do I give a player an effect when standing bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map. And I want to give the player levitation when standing on bedrock.

I tried this command:

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:bedrock effect @a minecraf:levitation 30
```

But I constantly get this error:

> [13:02:26] Failed to execute 'detect' as F1NN3RT

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is it executing @p but affecting @a ?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `execute detect` is:

```
/execute <entity> <x> <y> <z> detect <x> <y> <z> <block> <dataValue|blockState> <command>
```

You need a data value or block state (e.g: `0` or `default`) after `minecraft:bedrock`.

You've missed the `t` in `minecraf:levitation`.

You're also executing from `@p` but affecting `@a`. This would mean that if the closest player to the command block stands on bedrock, everyone will get levitation. Instead, you should make everyone (/`execute @a`) give themselves levitation (`/effect @a[c=1]`, to select theirself even if they're dead).

Try:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:bedrock 0 effect @a[c=1] minecraft:levitation 30
```